# Onclient click how to Change table's BG color using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I trying to change the background color of a table through Java script onClientClick. But the background doesn't change.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function compTableBGChange() {
    document.getElementById("tableComptag").style.backgroundColor = "Black";
}
</script>
```

My Table:

```
<table id="tableCompTag">
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Computer Tag"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBxCompTag" runat="server" Width="166px" ReadOnly="True">           
</asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnCompTagUpdate" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
onclick="btnCompTagUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="compTableBGChange()"/>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Visible="False" 
onclick="btnCancel_Click" />
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What's wrong in this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not preventing the button from posting back to server. So you should `return false` from `OnClientClick` or use an `HTMLInputButton` instead. If you want to postback, you should make the table `runat=server` and change the style on serverside via [HtmlTable.BgColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.bgcolor.aspx).

```
OnClientClick="compTableBGChange();return false;"
```

Apart from that, `document.getElementById` performs a **case-sensitive** match on the ID attribute(at least [in IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [in FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)).

So replace

```
document.getElementById("tableComptag")
```

with

```
document.getElementById("tableCompTag")
```

Comment: the background changes only for a second(I don't even have a chance to see the change) then it set back to defult color.

Comment: It works...!!!! I can now access the table from C# code behind the file and no need for java script. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

how about you try the onClientClick.
reference 
http://woaychee.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/call-javascript-from-aspnet-20-button-click/

```
 <asp:button runat="server" text="Click Me" OnClientClick="javascript:compTableBGChange()" id="myButton"></asp:button>
```

plus using the correct reference. tableCompTag